# Differences between Couchbase 3.0.1 and 4.0

Tags: couchbase

I have to write a library that works with Couchbase 3.0.1 *and* 4.0. I know that to know if my code will works with each one, I will have to test them.

Anyway, what are the key differences between both versions?

Comment: Will your library be using the Couchbase SDKs or no? Depending on what you are doing will tell me if what 4.0 has will effect what you are doing.

Comment: One obvious difference is N1QL which will be supported in 4.0
http://www.couchbase.com/preview/couchbase-server-4-0

Comment: 4.x has covering indexes, prepared statements and full DML support with N1QL queries.  It also offers multi-dimensional scaling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Java SDK, Couchbase server 4.0 is backwards compatible with the Java SDK 1.4.x. So using this version of the SDK should work across both Couchbase 3.0.x and 4.0.x servers, although you won't be able to use any of the cool new features with 4.0.x.

Other SDKs that were intended for Couchbase server 3.0.x should similarly be compatible with Couchbase server 4.0.x.

However, there could be some hidden "gotchas" when using an older SDK with the newer server version, although I have yet to encounter one myself.

As far as migrating from an older SDK intended for Couchbase server 3.0.x to a newer SDK intended for Couchbase server 4.0.x, this migration requires a significant effort for the Java SDK since they did a lot of refactoring. Although, I'm not certain if the same is true for SDKs in other languages.